# how to take input from space separated integers in c/c++?

Tags: c, string, input, enter

first line contains an integer N. Each of the next N lines contains at least 1 and at most 100 space separated distinct integers**(DEPENDS ON USER CHOICE)**.
For ex-

3 
5 100 1
2 
5 100

i want to store nos in a 2d array like 
    a[1][1] = 5 , a[1][2] =100, a[1][3] = 1
    a[2][1] =2 
    a[3][1] = 5, a[3][2] = 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, you can use the strtok() function.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   char str[80], first[12];
   char *token;
   int num, n, i;
   int ara[100][100]; // whatever size you want

   get(first);
   n = atoi(first);

   for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
     gets(str);
     token = strtok(str, " ");

     while( token != NULL ) 
     {
        num = atoi(token);
        printf( "%d\n", num );

        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
     }
   }

   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: A valiant effort on a not-so-great question. Kudos for being polite, yet putting the brakes on things.

Comment: thanks Tamim shahriar  :)... it worked ...

Comment: andrew barber .... thanks 4 ur advice, bt not needed on not so-great question.

Comment: @Tamim shahriar .. bt why while loop is incresing my k value of FOR loop im my code. ??